# Simulate clicking a submit in javascript

Tags: javascript, submit, google-chrome-extension

I want to be able to submit a form after a page loads automatically through Javascript.

> I am writing a google chrome extension.

So far the extension can fill in text in the input boxes but I can't figure out a way to get to the next step where the user would click Submit. Please help. Thank you.

**EDIT:** Pardon my edit. It wasn't clear that he was writing a chrome extension to those of us in the chatroom. --drachenstern

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you try something like `document.getElementById('myForm').submit()` ?

With a form like (after EDIT):

```
<form id="myform" action="/url/To/Action">
  ...
</form>
...
<script>
  document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
</script>
```

*EDIT after your comment*:
The `script` tag must be after the `form` tag. Or at the very end of the `body` tag if you want to be sure all the DOM elements are loaded.

Comment: This does work, I found a another issue else where in the code. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try document.getElementById('form1').submit();

Comment: Do you call this line when document is ready ? maybe you can put this line at the bottom of page ? Your form is empty ?

Comment: How can I do it for when the document is ready if I cannot change the HTML?

Comment: Can you use Jquery ? $(document).ready(function(){
   // Your code here
 });

Comment: hmmm... Sound like a good idea. I wouldn't want to import the jquery library for one function in the end though. Do you know the straight javascript equivalent to $(document).ready(function(){}?

Comment: Sure, you can see example here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery

Comment: To make it work without jQuery, add the `.submit()` command in a `script` tag at the end of the `body` tag. This will ensure that all the DOM is ready before you run your script.